# "We find 3 common strings as is."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I have a sentence like:

> We find 3 common strings as is.

What I mean in the sentence is that I find 3 common strings between two files appear as is.

Shall I use "as-is" or as is?

Comment: I don't understand what your example sentence is supposed to mean. It looks as if you might be using ***as is*** the way I might say *I'm selling my car "as is"* (i.e. - *in its current state*; I'm not going to clean or repair it, for example). That usage is normally enclosed in "scare quotes", but it doesn't really work in your context because we normally expect the context to *explicitly* name the thing that's being referred to as *in it's current state* (***my car*** in my example, but no such referent exists in your sentence, so it doesn't really make sense). The hyphen is ***optional***.

Comment: I mean identical strings in the two files. i.e. one string in file 1 appear as-is in file 2.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you say "a string" appears in two different files, what would it *mean* for either of those occurrences not to be "as is"? Can you please explain exactly what meaning you want "as is" to convey, in your context?

Comment: You should use neither. "as is" and "as-is" both mean "unmodified".  I think you may be misunderstanding a definition that says "as found".  What that means is "not changed in any way--just as we found it."  *I am selling my old jalopy "as-is"* and that means the buyer must accept it in its present condition, just as the buyer finds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean identical strings in the two files. i.e. one string in file 1 appear as-is in file 2. –

We find **the same** string (of characters) in two files.

Comment: I think we could also write: _We find **an identical** string in two characters_. I’m not sure why “the same” sounds better than “a same,” yet “an identical” sounds better than “the identical” (at least, it’s that way in my ear). But you and I both agree that the “as is” is both unneeded and confusing – with or without the hyphen.